# Segmentation fault error. Trying to loop a python program

Tags: rpi.gpio, python-3, apache-httpd, gsm

I'm using AT commands to send data over http, but the problem is that sometimes the program has an error and wont run again until I reboot and the GSM. Im using a crontab and also running the file as local file on boot. How could I fix the program to just begin the script again? How do I fix segmentation fault error.

Comment: This is not a valid program, so it's not clear what's happening.  Segmentation fault means you're writing to an illegal memory address somewhere (or a library that you're calling is), but there's no way to tell where that's happening with this fragment of code.

Comment: Hello. Could you move the error message from your comment to the question, reading it all bunched up with no formatting is a little difficult.

Comment: Getting better.  Now we have the program but we don't know where the error occurs.

Comment: This is not a Pi question, but a general programming question. You are asking us to debug a poorly structured python program. You should split the code into modules and debug each module

Comment: @Milliways I meant to tag python actually, and I don't believe I asked you to debug anything. I was just asking those that might know something about the error to take a look. I didn't say it was perfect; however does have days were errors don't occur. I appreciate you're feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the interpreter is attempting to iterate `result`, which (in the case your program crashes) isn't iterable because it's of type`NoneType`. It seems like `execute()` returns `None` in `result = execute(cmd)`. Looking at that function, there are two possibilities:

1. `port.read(100).decode()` returns `None`. That's unlikely the case because the function is supposed to return an iterable type. Returning `None` in any case is prone to crashes and bad practice.
2. There is an exception in `execute()`. In this case (`except`) the function will not return anything (`None`) which I'm pretty sure is what crashes your program.

Comment: Where does it answer a question to Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I think, it answers this question at least. Whether the question is on raspberry pi or not is another story.

Comment: But due to our policies it should be a story.